# Python - Matplotlib: scaling a log-scaled histogram by a square root

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to change the scale ON TOP OF THE LOGARITHMIC SCALE by taking the square root of both axis. I hope this is clear. Basically I want to do that, to see if I get a histogram whose shape is a line.

However how do I change this? To make it clearer I want to take the logarithm of the bins and of the data. After that, I want to take the square root of the bins and the data. Is there a command in matplotlib or a strategy to do it?

Here is my MCVE, which is just a remake of the documentation found [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50,log=True)

plt.axis([40, 160, 0, 800])
plt.show()
```

Now I want to add an additional scaling on top of the log scaling, by a square root. Indeed the graph that I get is a parabola:

[image]

And now I want to see whether by now scaling it as a square root, I get a line (which should work mathematically)

> Is my procedure even correct for obtaining the log scale? And how do I go about scaling it further with a square root?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: short version w/o the MCVE: compute the histogram directly with `numpy.histogram`, apply transformations to the results, plot with `Axes.bar`

Comment: @PaulH I will try to write a mcve

Comment: @PaulH I've edited it!

Comment: @PaulH I'm trying to do what you said. So in my MCVE I basically called `nnew = np.sqrt(n)` and `binsnew = np.sqrt(bins)`. So now they have the correct transformation. But you said I should plot with `axes.bar`. How should I use it?

Comment: @PaulH I tried using the barlpot as I think that is what you meant. So I wrote `nnew = np.sqrt(n)
binsnew = np.sqrt(bins)` and then `ax = plt.axes()` and finally `plt.bar(binsnew, nnew)
plt.show()` but it still doesn't work!

Comment: @PaulH it gives me the following error: `incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 51 or scalar` . However `len(binsnew)=51' and `len(nnew)=50`, which sounds correct as there should be one more bin than frequencies

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar

Comment: @PaulH I tried to solve it by deleting the last element and then adding a width made of the difference between any two items in bins. For instance:
`binsnew = np.delete(np.sqrt(bins),len(bins)-1)` and the width would be `width = binsnew[7]-binsnew[6]`